# How can i use multithreading in discord.py?

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, python-multithreading, python-class

I've recently tried doing some image generating with craiyon's API, and send the image through discord.py,
But i realized that it takes a long time and it would stop the entire bot from working all together.
I tried to implement multithreading, but i had no way to send the image back inside of the class i instance using `threading.Thread()`

Code:

```
class message_del:
    def __init__(self, message):
        self._message = message
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.images)
        t.start()

    def images(self):
        if self._message.content == "$image":
            generator = Craiyon()
            result = generator.generate(self._message.content)
            result.save_images()
            self._message.reply(file=discord.File("generated//image-1.jpg"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message_del(message)
```

with it i get this error:
`RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`
please help

I tried adding async and await to the class, but `__init__` doesn't return take async
then i tried ditching all of this and creating the image then sending it through another function, but that didn't work cuz of the async stuff. So i got stuck.